# Using the identifier of a variable as input in Pascal

Tags: variables, input, pascal

So let's say I have some variables for example x:=1, y:=2 and z:=3
Is there a way to input just x , y or z
and get the value of the variable as output?
ex:
User's input: y
output : 2

I tried using if then structure, but I have 32 variables, so it's gonna be very messy

Answer (score 0):

You want to look up the value of a variable at runtime based on the name of the variable? No, that is not possible, or if possible, not something that should be relied on. The names used in your source code are there for readability of the source code. They may be completely changed or removed in the executable code.

What you may want is a map which can associate string (other other types) values with a value of some other type.  If you're using FreePascal, you might use [TFPGMap](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/fgl/tfpgmap.html) to accomplish this.